# How to appear an emoji in TinyMCE version 5.06?

Tags: tinymce, emoticons, tinymce-5

I am trying to insert an emoji by using TinyMCE 5.06 version, but there is an error about this inserting. An emoji does not appear when I use Html.Raw() in Asp.Net MVC. It looks like this " ????". How can I fix this ?

```
  //tinymce plugin and toolbar options
        $scope.tinymceOptions = {
            selector: '#post',         
            plugins: [
               "advlist autolink autoresize link image fullscreen  lists charmap paste print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking wordcount  ",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste template spellchecker searchreplace help imagetools media "
            ], 
            mobile: {
                theme: "mobile",
                plugins: [ 'autosave', 'lists', 'autolink' ],
                toolbar: [ 'undo', 'bold', 'italic', 'styleselect' ]
            },
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline left aligncenter alignright alignjustify | forecolor  backcolor | fontselect fontsizeselect| bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media  preview |  emoticons | searchreplace  help ",
            toolbar_items_size: 'small',
            file_picker_types: 'file image media',
            image_title: true,
            automatic_uploads: true,          
            file_picker_types: 'image',
            relative_urls: false,
            file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
                input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
                input.onchange = function () {
                    var file = this.files[0];

                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function () {

                        var id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                        blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                };
                input.click();
            },

            media_url_resolver: function (data, resolve/*, reject*/) {
                if (data.url.indexOf('YOUR_SPECIAL_VIDEO_URL') !== -1) {
                    var embedHtml = '<iframe src="' + data.url +
                    '" width="400" height="400" ></iframe>';
                    resolve({html: embedHtml});
                } else {
                    resolve({html: ''});
                }
            },
            width: "98%",
        };
```

I expect the output to be  or  as examples, but the actual output is ?? .

Answer (score 8):

Had this problem.

```
entity_encoding: "numeric"
```

This will send the emoticon to your DB as HTML Dec code, then when you display them as HTML dec code, your browser will convert them to emoticons.

Answer (score 1):

Check which character set you're using to process the HTML string. This can happen when you accidentally convert a string from a complex character set (required for emoji) such as Unicode or UTF-8 into something simpler like ASCII.